# Magento Attribute Set cant save Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-set

Servus,

when i try to save `Attributes` to an `Attribute Set`, i get the confirmation that its been saved. When i reopen the Set, no attribute is saved to my Set.

Log file says:

> ERR (3): Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array  in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/SetController.php on line 138

Magento 1.9.3.2

```
$data = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()-getPost('data'));
$data['attribute_set_name'] = $helper->stripTags($data['attribute_set_name']);
$model->organizeData($data);
```

Comment: The PHP error is very explicit. $data is not an array. Your code assumes that $data will always be an array, and will always contain 'attribute_set_name'. Are you certain that $data is always going to contain a valid array? What is the value of $data when you get this error?

Comment: Value is just a 1

Comment: I should say, we transfered all attributes and products by database from a other magento-store (same Version). Maybe i missed a table, all products and shop are working fine.